# Replace the string array value

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

My string structure is below. I want to insert the new value in fourth position instead of old one.How can i insert it.

```
Array structure :


arr_val[0]="100";
arr_val[1]="300";
arr_val[2]="150";
arr_val[3]="360"; //I want to replace this value and insert 200 in this array
arr_val[4]="100";
arr_val[5]="300";
```

I can't sure the fourth value may be changed.

Comment: You can do the same when you added the initial value. Or is something more complicated that you want? Is there a pattern for values you want to replace?

Comment: What's wrong with simple assignment `arr_val[3] = "200"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you did when you initialized your Arrayvariable you can do it to set a new value:

```
arr_val[3] = "200";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//arr_val[3]="360"; //I want to replace this value and insert 200 in this array
arr_val[3]="200";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a trick question or not, but you've already got the right syntax:

```
arr_val[3]="200";
```